# Moving from Yarn to Npm in Rails project breaks Webpacker with missing dependencies errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, webpacker

I am migrating a Rails project from Yarn to Npm because my team doesn't plan on upgrading to Yarn Berry. I've removed all traces of Yarn and replaced them with Npm and followed [this Rails/Webpacker/Npm tutorial](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-webpacker-with-npm-instead-of-yarn-a8a764e3a8ab).

When starting my webpack server with `npm run webpack-dev-server` however, I run into the following errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in './node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'
```

Not sure what could be causing this error. I've deleted `yarn.lock` and the `node_modules` directory multiple times to no avail.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/hoek": "^8.5.1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.x",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "camelize2": "^1.0.0",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffeescript": "^1.12.7",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "consolidate": "^0.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "file-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "got": "^8.0.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.5.2",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "mem": "^4.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "node-gyp": "^4.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "path-complete-extname": "^0.1.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "precss": "^2.0.0",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.5.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.9",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
    "whiskers": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.30",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.5",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  }
}
```

Here is my `bin/webpack-dev-server` script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$stdout.sync = true

require "shellwords"
require "yaml"

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "development"
RAILS_ENV = ENV["RAILS_ENV"]

ENV["NODE_ENV"] ||= RAILS_ENV
NODE_ENV = ENV["NODE_ENV"]

APP_PATH          = File.expand_path("../", __dir__)
CONFIG_FILE       = File.join(APP_PATH, "config/webpacker.yml")
NODE_MODULES_PATH = File.join(APP_PATH, "node_modules")
WEBPACK_CONFIG    = File.join(APP_PATH, "config/webpack/development.js")

def args(key)
  index = ARGV.index(key)
  index ? ARGV[index + 1] : nil
end

begin
  dev_server = YAML.load_file(CONFIG_FILE)["development"]["dev_server"]

  protocol = args('--https') || dev_server["https"] ? 'https' : 'http'
  host = args('--host') || dev_server["host"]
  port = args('--port') || dev_server["port"]

  DEV_SERVER_HOST = "#{protocol}://#{host}:#{port}".freeze
rescue Errno::ENOENT, NoMethodError
  puts "Webpack dev_server configuration not found in #{CONFIG_FILE}."
  puts "Please run bundle exec rails webpacker:install to install webpacker"
  exit!
end

newenv = {
  "NODE_PATH" => NODE_MODULES_PATH.shellescape,
  "ASSET_HOST" => DEV_SERVER_HOST.shellescape
}.freeze

cmdline = ["npm", "run", "webpack-dev-server", "--color", "--config", WEBPACK_CONFIG] + ARGV

Dir.chdir(APP_PATH) do
  exec newenv, *cmdline
end
```

Let me know if more code snippets would be helpful to help debug!

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution to your problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you found a solution?